# Select box's text strangely large in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In Safari, Chrome, and Opera a `<select>` box with a size of `20px` looks like this:

[image]

But in Firefox, however, it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it? Thanks!

EDIT: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ckwh0rno/) a Fiddle so you can test it yourself.

EDIT2: This appears the be a Mac OS X problem, as someone with Windows did not see it.

Comment: Looks exactly the same here on Chrome, IE11 and Firefox. Maybe try pressing CTRL-0 on FF.

Comment: Try setting `-moz-appearance:none;` this resets the default browser styles since every browser brings their own to some elements.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on OSX and @Michael_B is using windows. (just using safari and IE11 browsers to determine that). I'm also on OSX and that occurs for me, firefox has unusually large text

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan: I tried that just now and it made the select box look like this: http://i.imgur.com/0BswkLA.png

Comment: @Madivad: So it's an OS X problem. Interesting.

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, but I'd suggest looking up Firefox default CSS and possibly add osx to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `em` it will give you more standard across all browsers. `20px = 1.25em`

[Here are other options to chose from](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: I tried using `em` and it didn't change anything. Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the default styling for select boxes in webkit and Firefox with [these lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance):

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

However, it's a finicky and non-standard solution. The font-size will change, but you'll lose all the other stuff, too, including the arrows.

Select boxes are notoriously difficult to style. There are some great third-party libraries like [Selectize](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/), [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), or [select2](https://select2.github.io/), which actually replace the select element with a style-able DOM tree and use events to manipulate the select behind the scenes. You may find these easier to use.